# Use setxkbmap to make CapsLock act like a 3rd Shift key?

Tags: custom-keyboard, capslock

I've gotten used to having the Ctrl key being located below the Shift key instead of above.
I occasionally hit the CapsLock by mistake and would like to map to act like another Shift key.

Searching the web, I see plenty of postings on how to map it to a Ctrl key, or swap the CapsLock <-> Ctrl, so please don't tell me how to do these.

Also I only want to know the parameters for setxkbmap not xmod. I've looked at system configuration files but still haven't figured out which names I need to use.

Comment: On a side-note, I can make the
`
     CapsLock -> Ctrl
`
setting persistent by adding this line
`
     XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps
`
to this file
`
     /etc/default/keyboard
`
So it's just a matter of getting it to act like a Shift.

Comment: Sorry the comment above reads like junk, but the formatting instructions don't work, and now it won't let me edit it any more or delete it and re-do it.....